# Zookeeper using high CPU

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am new to zookeeper and I have a single node zookeeper setup on a system having 2 cores and 16 GB RAM. The number of active connections on zookeeper is near about 700.And it is taking 2 GB of RAM and 100% CPU(on both the cores). I am unable to find out what is causing this high CPU Utilization

My Zookeeper Config is:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
# 
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
# 
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
dataDir=/path
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=0
```

and the zookeeper logs are:

```
[2016-12-30 08:14:47,057] INFO Client attempting to establish new session at /10.179.63.152:43480 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2016-12-30 08:14:47,107] INFO Established session 0x1594ae64cde0188 with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /xx.xxx.xx.xxx:43480 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2016-12-30 08:14:48,099] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1594ae64cde0188 type:create cxid:0x2 zxid:0xa798c81b txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2016-12-30 08:14:48,100] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1594ae64cde0188 type:create cxid:0x3 zxid:0xa798c81c txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers/prod Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers/prod (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2016-12-30 08:14:48,101] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1594ae64cde0188 type:create cxid:0x4 zxid:0xa798c81d txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers/prod/ids Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers/prod/ids (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2016-12-30 08:15:25,273] INFO Accepted socket connection from /10.185.3.226:58898 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2016-12-30 08:15:25,284] INFO Client attempting to establish new session at /xx.xxx.xx.xxx:58898 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2016-12-30 08:15:25,347] INFO Established session 0x1594ae64cde0189 with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /xx.xxx.xx.xxx:58898 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2016-12-30 08:15:26,762] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1594ae64cde0189 type:create cxid:0x2 zxid:0xa798cb43 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2016-12-30 08:15:26,762] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1594ae64cde0189 type:create cxid:0x3 zxid:0xa798cb44 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers/prod Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers/prod (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2016-12-30 08:15:26,763] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1594ae64cde0189 type:create cxid:0x4 zxid:0xa798cb45 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers/prod/ids Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers/prod/ids (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2016-12-30 08:15:56,786] INFO Accepted socket connection from /xx.xxx.xx.xxx:43574 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2016-12-30 08:15:56,790] INFO Client attempting to establish new session at /xx.xxx.xx.xxx:43574 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2016-12-30 08:15:56,843] INFO Established session 0x1594ae64cde018a with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /10.185.178.18:43574 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2016-12-30 08:15:57,743] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1594ae64cde018a type:create cxid:0x2 zxid:0xa798db9d txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2016-12-30 08:15:57,743] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1594ae64cde018a type:create cxid:0x3 zxid:0xa798db9e txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers/prod Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers/prod (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2016-12-30 08:15:57,744] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1594ae64cde018a type:create cxid:0x4 zxid:0xa798db9f txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers/prod/ids Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers/prod/ids (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
```

Can someone help me identify the problem .

Comment: I think this is no abnormal situation since the standalone server has to keep 700 connections open and (depending on your application) serve hundreds of clients (out of those connections, at a given second there will be hundreds of clients actively communicating with the server). Correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha -  there is too much fluctuation in the CPU at 700 connection CPU shows 9% and as soon as connection reaches 800 it hits up to 100 %.So Whats the correct way to handle this?

Comment: I think it is better if you can put this question in `zookeeper user mailing list (user@zookeeper.apache.org)`